# Determining the signs of the elements of the output vector in matrix-vector multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let's say that we are multiplying a 2-by-1 and 2-by-2 matrix and that we know their elements. Is there any way to know, *without computing the matrix-vector product*, what the signs of the elements in the output vector will be? In other words, can we know which quadrant the output vector will end up in, but not necessarily what the actual coordinates will be? Furthermore, can we know which element is greater in absolute value?

Comment: without any further information? no

Comment: @Exodd Sorry, I realized that I should have specified that we know the elements of the matrices. I am not sure if that was obvious. Is that an example of what you meant by "further information?"